# Creating web page in non-english language

Tags: html, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to use non-English language (ex: Bengali) in my website. I am using the following tag which is not working.

My project encoding is widows-1252. I am using net-beans 7.0 with font Arial Unicode MS.
Is it mandatory to change my project encoding to UTF-8 or  other ways are there?
Please help

```
<%@ page     language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8 pageEncoding="UTF-8"  %>
<META  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<table >
        <tr >
              <td >বাঙালি </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to change my project encoding to UTF-8 or other ways are there?

You can use any encoding that supports the characters you need (widows-1252 won't do the job for you since it is for the Latin alphabet). Support for Unicode (which supports just about every language) has been excellent since around the turn of the century. You should have been using it for all new projects for the last decade and a half.

Other than changing to an encoding that supports the characters you need, you can use [HTML character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references). Typically this will be:

> Decimal numeric character reference
>   The ampersand must be followed by a "#" (U+0023) character, followed by one or more ASCII digits,
>   representing a base-ten integer that corresponds to a Unicode code
>   point that is allowed according to the definition below. The digits
>   must then be followed by a ";" (U+003B) character.

Since character references are expressed in ASCII characters, you can express them in any encoding (as they build on top of ASCII).